# Changing Local Admin Password Using Encrypted Password.txt

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to update a local admin account password.  I don't want to pass the password in plain text, so i found a workflow (https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/) that will allow me to encrypt PW's.

```
#Change password for TestAccount
$User = 'TestAccount'
$PasswordFile = "$PsScriptRoot\Password.txt"
$KeyFile = "$PsScriptRoot\AES.key"
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ` -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)

$adsiUser = [adsi]"WinNT://localhost/$User,user"
$adsiUser.SetPassword($MyCredential.Password)
```

I received the error

```
Exception calling "SetPassword" with "1" argument(s): "Type mismatch. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"
```

So my google-fu allowed me to decrypt the password with

```
$decodedpassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($MyCredential.Password))
```

But now there's a trail of cookies in my script... is there any way to pass this as a Secure String?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/04/21/using-saved-credentials-securely-in-powershell-scripts/
It explains how to save passwords securely using the Windows Data protection API. You cant save the password on the machine without the machine being able to decode the password. If that is an issue you need to look into obfuscating the script itself...

Answer (score 0):

Use the Built-in method `GetNetworkCredential()` to get the plain text password from the Credential Object

So Change this line:

```
$adsiUser.SetPassword($MyCredential.Password)
```

To This:

```
$adsiUser.SetPassword($MyCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
```

For short Credential Save/Load Tutorial:

```
#To Save Credential to file
$pass = "123456" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$pass | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content c:\temp\pass.txt

#To Load Credential From Text
$username = "userName"
$encrypted = Get-Content c:\temp\pass.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username, $encrypted) 

#To Show the Plain text Password from the Credential Object
$credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```